# Mistake in Sql query while splitting string

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

What mistake I am making in this sql query

```
    Declare @str Varchar(100) = 'asasa,bsasas,csasa,dsczxvvc'
    declare @d varchar(2)=','

SELECT 
     RIGHT(LEFT(@str,Number-1), 
    CHARINDEX(@d,REVERSE(LEFT(@d+@str,Number-1)))) 
FROM 
    master..spt_values
WHERE 
    Type = 'P' AND Number BETWEEN 1 AND  LEN(@str)
    AND SUBSTRING(@str,Number,1) = @d
```

**Expected Result**

```
(No column name)
asasa
bsasas
csasa
dsczxvvc
```

**Actual Result**

```
(No column name)
asasa
bsasas
csasa
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your  `AND SUBSTRING(@str, Number, 1) = @d` is forcing a comma to be at the end of `dsczxvvc`...there isn't one. `asasa,bsasas,csasa,dsczxvvc,` works.

Answer (score 1):

add one more comma at the end of string

you can directly add comma in the string like = **"asasa,bsasas,csasa,dsczxvvc,"**

or

handle this thing in sql side.

Declare @str Varchar(100)
 set @str = 'asasa,bsasas,csasa,dsczxvvc'
    declare @d varchar(2)
    set @d =','

**set @str = @str + ','**

SELECT 
     RIGHT(LEFT(@str,Number-1), 
    CHARINDEX(@d,REVERSE(LEFT(@d+@str,Number-1)))) 
FROM 
    master..spt_values
WHERE 
    Type = 'P' AND Number BETWEEN 1 AND  LEN(@str)
    AND SUBSTRING(@str,Number,1) = @d

Answer (score 1):

This is because since the last string portion does not have the seperator at the end of the string
If you add the following code just before the SELECT statement, it will work

```
set @str = @str + @d
```

There are many split functions on the web, you can use one of them actually.

[Split string using CLR function](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/sql-server-string-split-tsql-clr-function-sample.aspx)

[Split using XML](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/t-sql-convert-split-delimeted-string-as-rows-using-xml.aspx)

[SQL Server split string function](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/sql-server-t-sql-split-function.aspx)